# mysqldump option to include column names in first row

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysqldump to dump all my tables to CSV files like so:

mysqldump -u  -p -t -TC:\Temp  --fields-terminated-by=,

Is there an option to have mysqldump include the column names in the first row of each file?

Comment: This was answered in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467517/mysqldump-create-column-names-for-inserts-when-backing-up

Comment: @AndyMornes No, that answer is about a SQL dump, not about CSV export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not; you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: After much googling I was coming to that conclusion.

Answer (score 6):

As of MySQL 5.5 (perhaps before) you can now use `--complete-insert` or `-c` to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql test -e"select * from users" | tr '\t' ',' > tocsv.csv
```

This may not be exact but very close to what you are trying to.