# Mysqldump: create column names for inserts when backing up

Tags: mysql, database-schema

How do I instruct mysqldump to backup with column names in insert statements?
In my case I didn’t a normal back up with insert sql’s resulting in

```
LOCK TABLES `users` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` 
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (1
```

structure.

Now I went ahead and **removed a column** from the schema in users. After this when I run the backup sql’s I get a **column number mismatch error**.

To fix this how do I go about instructing mysqldump to write column names too? 
Here is how I do it now

```
mysqldump --host=${dbserver} --user=${dbusername} --password=${dbpassword} \
          --no-create-db --no-create-info --extended-insert --single-transaction \
          --compress tablename
```

On a broader level, what’s the best practice to manage these schema changes?

Comment: How will explicitly specified fields help you? After you have deleted a column even query with specified fields will be incorrect.

Comment: @zerkms It will help when you only have added fields to a table. If there have been fields deleted, they should be removed entirely

Answer (score 226):

Use `--complete-insert` in the mysqldump command params

Comment: Is there a sane reason why this should not be the default behaviour for mysqldump?

Comment: @paradiso I believe that is because `mysqldump` is heavily used for backups, and it is a nice thing that they are as smaller as possible.

Comment: @paradiso also note that mysqldump is by default dumping the structure and the data, thus making the column names information useless. Having column names specified is useful when you load values into a table whose structure may differ from the one you extracted the data from.

Comment: @paradiso The smaller the file the better. Not including column names drops the size of the file substantially depending on the complexity of your database

Comment: But in some case like mine it's kind of life saving, I've local database that's getting changes day to day but not instantly goes to live server, so when I got to update the live server db then it's definitely a life saving for me, otherwise i'd have to track all column names that i've added to my local shema's and then add those columns with add columns manually for each table. but with this simple trick i can save many times and headache.

Comment: An indication where having the column names is helpful: I have a django project, that when built from scratch places the columns in a different order to the dump. I suppose this has happened because the column names/structure has changed over time. Became a particular problem moving from MySQL to PostgreSQL. But --complete-insert solved it.